# Linux kernel difference between protected and reserved memory? (memmap parameter)

Tags: linux, memory, kernel-parameters

The Linux kernel takes a `memmap` parameter *) to manually designate memory regions for different use-cases.

Q: What is the difference between **reserved** memory (`memmap=nn[KMG]$ss[KMG]`) and **protected** memory (`memmap=nn[KMG]!ss[KMG]`)?

I.e. how are they treated by the kernel and when is either used?

In regards to `/proc/iomem`, I believe reserved memory is listed as `Reserved`, and protected memory is listed as `RAM buffer`. Is that correct?

---

*) I found no good linkable reference page that isn't a wall of text, so I'm appending a copy from the [kernel docs](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.19/admin-guide/kernel-parameters.html):

```
memmap=exactmap [KNL,X86] Enable setting of an exact
                E820 memory map, as specified by the user.
                Such memmap=exactmap lines can be constructed based on
                BIOS output or other requirements. See the memmap=nn@ss
                option description.

memmap=nn[KMG]@ss[KMG]
                [KNL] Force usage of a specific region of memory.
                Region of memory to be used is from ss to ss+nn.
                If @ss[KMG] is omitted, it is equivalent to mem=nn[KMG],
                which limits max address to nn[KMG].
                Multiple different regions can be specified,
                comma delimited.
                Example:
                        memmap=100M@2G,100M#3G,1G!1024G

memmap=nn[KMG]#ss[KMG]
                [KNL,ACPI] Mark specific memory as ACPI data.
                Region of memory to be marked is from ss to ss+nn.

memmap=nn[KMG]$ss[KMG]
                [KNL,ACPI] Mark specific memory as reserved.
                Region of memory to be reserved is from ss to ss+nn.
                Example: Exclude memory from 0x18690000-0x1869ffff
                         memmap=64K$0x18690000
                         or
                         memmap=0x10000$0x18690000
                Some bootloaders may need an escape character before '$',
                like Grub2, otherwise '$' and the following number
                will be eaten.

memmap=nn[KMG]!ss[KMG]
                [KNL,X86] Mark specific memory as protected.
                Region of memory to be used, from ss to ss+nn.
                The memory region may be marked as e820 type 12 (0xc)
                and is NVDIMM or ADR memory.

memmap=<size>%<offset>-<oldtype>+<newtype>
                [KNL,ACPI] Convert memory within the specified region
                from <oldtype> to <newtype>. If "-<oldtype>" is left
                out, the whole region will be marked as <newtype>,
                even if previously unavailable. If "+<newtype>" is left
                out, matching memory will be removed. Types are
                specified as e820 types, e.g., 1 = RAM, 2 = reserved,
                3 = ACPI, 12 = PRAM.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Reserved** memory is memory the kernel cannot/should not use as regular memory, for whatever reason.

**Protected** memory (sometimes also known as *persistent memory*) is memory that is guaranteed to keep its contents through a reboot or power loss, either because it is a [Non-Volatile DIMM (NVDIMM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NVDIMM) or for some other reason.

e820 type 12 is tricky to interpret because in some systems pre-dating ACPI 6.0 it was used to indicate NVDIMMs, i.e. **protected/persistent memory**, but ACPI 6.0 defines that as type 7, and re-defines type 12 as "OEM reserved".

Comments in kernel's [arch/x86/include/asm/e820/types.h](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/arch/x86/include/asm/e820/types.h) indicate some older systems also used type 6 to indicate protected/persistent memory, i.e. the early NVDIMM support was a vendor-specific mess until ACPI 6.0 provided new definitions (and re-defined the old ones to mean "don't touch this mess").

Linux apparently ignores the persistence capabilities of e820 type 12 memory unless the `CONFIG_X86_PMEM_LEGACY=y` is set.

Answer (score 1):

This is only a partial answer.  Via testing, I learned:

For a linux command line such as: `memmap=0x8000000$0x1d000000` (note that for grub you need to quote it in grub.conf: `memmap=0x8000000\$0x1d000000`), you get the following line during boot:

```
reserve setup_data: [mem 0x000000001d000000-0x0000000024ffffff] reserved
```

For a linux command line: `memmap=0x8000000!0x1d000000`, you get the following line during boot:

```
reserve setup_data: [mem 0x000000001d000000-0x0000000024ffffff] persistent (type 12)
```

With the addition of the kernel command line option `iomem=relaxed`, in the **reserved** configuration I was able to access `/dev/mem`, mmap, and read/write the `0x1d000000` range.  When I used the **protected** configuration, I was unable to access it via `/dev/mem` (and I did get a message: `x86/PAT: peek:9098 map pfn expected mapping type uncached-minus for [mem 0x1d000000-0x1d000fff], got write-back`).

For more indirectly related information about this stuff, I found [Linux Kernel x86 PAT documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v5.7/x86/pat.html).  I imagine it is informative, but this also didn't really reveal the difference between protected and reserved, but look at this [question/answer for more information about uncached-minus, mmap, and stuff like that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53196359/mmap-dma-memory-uncached-map-pfn-ram-range-req-uncached-minus-got-write-back).  For what it is worth, `/sys/kernel/debug/x86/pat_memtype_list`  and `/proc/mtrr` does not list the mapping listed above when in the **reserved** configuration.

Slightly more relevant, as I said above "persisent (type 12)" which decodes as `E820_TYPE_PRAM` (aka `IORES_DESC_PERSISTENT_MEMORY_LEGACY`), and "reserved" as `E820_TYPE_RESERVED` (aka `IORES_DESC_RESERVED`).  More specifically, in [arch/x86/kernel/e820.c](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/torvalds/linux/master/arch/x86/kernel/e820.c) you can see the parsing of the kernel command line.

Despite all of this information, I still don't fundamentally understand the difference.  Maybe someone can eventually answer this question.  But maybe this will be enough information for people to resolve whatever problem they have.

Comment: Thank you for the in-depth answer. But the other one was more definitive. I wish I could give you extra credit or accept two answers.